# How can I use InStr to test for a broader value?

Tags: excel, vba

I currently use this code to search for a specific value entered by the user. However, I'd like it to test for the value if it's located within the string, for example, if the user typed "Jon" the search results could be "Jon, Jonathan, Jones" etc. I'm thinking I need to utilize the InStr function somehow, but I'm not sure how to set it up... Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Select
    Dim MyValue As String
    MyValue = TextBox1.Value
    If MyValue = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a sales managers name!"
        TextBox1.SetFocus
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        Range("A3:I200").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Me.Hide
        Set i = Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set E = Sheets("Sheet2")
        Dim d
        Dim j
        d = 2
        j = 2
        Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("A" & j))
            If i.Range("A" & j) = MyValue Then
                d = d + 1
                E.Rows(d).Value = i.Rows(j).Value
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("H1").Select
        If Range("A3").Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "No results were found."
        Else
            MsgBox "Results were found!"
        End If
    End If
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: You can split on a space to get individual words but punctuation fouls this up and needs to be accounted for. Similarly, `instr(1, " "&i.Range("A" & j)&" ", " "&myvalue" ", vbtextcompare)` gets fouled up the same way.

Comment: Hmm, so perhaps I can add some kind of error handler in case punctuation is typed in the textbox?

Comment: Strip the punctuation out before splitting. You've provided no sample data so no relevant solution can be offered.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being ambiguous. Column A contains a lot of names like "Jon S", "Jonathan Samson", "jonanthan s", "Jonthan Samson". Right now the search for MyValue only returns an exact match, not a broad one like I'm trying to have it do. But I see what you're saying now, strip out punctuation like "." before splitting. Makes more sense than an error handler for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `AutoFilter()`, and make some little refactoring as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim MyValue As String

    MyValue = Me.TextBox1.Value
    If MyValue = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a sales managers name!"
        Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
    Else
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=MyValue & "*"
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.ClearContents
                    Intersect(.Parent.UsedRange, .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3")
                    MsgBox "Results were found."
                Else
                    MsgBox "No results were found."
                End If
            End With
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
        Me.Hide '<--| hide the userform and move 'Unload UserformName' command to the sub that's calling the Userform
    End If        
End Sub
```

Comment: @dwirony, did you get through it?

Comment: Hi user3598756, unfortunately this solution didn't work as intended... It still doesn't pick up on names that I'm intending it to....

Comment: what kind of matches are not picked up?

Comment: Well before it was able to pick up EXACT matches, but with this new one it's not picking up on any matches :(. I'm not sure what the matter is with the code you've posted. I've been working on this recently myself with my original code (I added Option Compare Text to the top so it will at least ignore case sensitivity) but I still can't pick up on strings that contain parts of myvalue

Comment: try edited code: only changed `.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=MyValue & "*"`

Comment: And there it is! It's working now! I was looking at the "* *" wondering what the purpose of that was... Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are welcome. the purpose of "* **" was to get only occurrences of some "Jon*" name in conjunction with a surname (separated by a space), since that's what I (erroneously) got was your need

Comment: Uh oh... We have a problem now... I should've known.... Naturally I protect the first 2 rows of my document (which contain headers). Even after changing `With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))`
to `With .Range("A3", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))` I'm still getting the error that I cant use autofilter on a protected sheet... any solution to this?

Comment: unprotect it (after `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` place `.Unprotect`) and and the protect it again before exiting (place `.Protect` before `End With`)

Comment: Good solution. Ty!~

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with a regular expression in the form of something like:

`(^Jon\s)|(\sJon\s)|(\sJon$)`

I'd wrap it in a function to allow building the pattern dynamically from user input. This is just an example - you'd either need to do some more escaping beyond just the `.` or (probably better) add input restrictions on the TextBox.

```
'Add reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions
Private Function ContainsWord(target As String, search As String) As Boolean
    Const template As String = "(^<word>\s)|(\s<word>\s)|(\s<word>$)"
    Dim expression As String
    expression = Replace$(template, "<word>", Replace$(search, ".", "\."))
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = expression
        ContainsWord = .Test(target)
    End With
End Function
```

Sample usage:

```
Public Sub Example()
    Debug.Print ContainsWord("foo bar baz", "bar")  'True
    Debug.Print ContainsWord("foo barbaz", "bar")  'False
    Debug.Print ContainsWord("foobar baz", "bar")  'False
    Debug.Print ContainsWord("bar foo baz", "bar")  'True
    Debug.Print ContainsWord("foo baz bar", "bar")  'True
End Sub
```

In your code, you'd just replace the line...

> ```
> If i.Range("A" & j) = MyValue Then
> ```

...with:

```
If ContainsWord(i.Range("A" & j).Value, MyValue) Then
```

Note that since you are calling it in a loop, you'd probably want to cache the `RegExp` in your case though to avoid repeatedly creating it if you have a ton of cells to check.

Comment: I'm sorry Cominterm, but looking at your example using "bar" that is not my intended effect. I'd like it to pick up on ANY word that contains "bar", even if the word was "foobarbaz". It looks like your example would only pick up on bar if it was separate from the other words.

Comment: Back to my original example, if the user entered "Jon" I'd like it to pull occurences of "Jonathan, Jonly" etc. etc.